# Npgsql: why `Activity.Duration` is much lower than actual elapsed time?

Tags: .net, npgsql, open-telemetry

I don't understand how `Npgsql` calculates the duration, because the elapsed time captured with `Stopwatch` is an order of magnitude higher.
I was expecting a much closer duration between the two measurements.

On my machine I have this times:

```
Activity.Duration:   00:00:00.0174913
Stopwatch duration:  00:00:00.1394318
```

---

You can reproduce by creating a .NET console application

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using Npgsql;
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

using var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
    .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("npgsql-tester"))
    .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
    .AddSource("MyApp")
    .AddNpgsql()
    .AddConsoleExporter()
    .Build();

var connectionString = "Host=localhost;Database=db;Username=dbuser;Password=dbpassword;";
await using var dataSource = NpgsqlDataSource.Create(connectionString);
await using var cmd = dataSource.CreateCommand("SELECT 1");

var timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();

await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();

timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Stopwatch duration: {timer.Elapsed}");
```

Add the dependencies

```
dotnet add package Npgsql -v 7.0.2
dotnet add package Npgsql.OpenTelemetry -v 7.0.2
dotnet add package OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console -v 1.4.0
dotnet add package OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient -v 1.0.0-rc9.13
```

Launch a local Postgres instance with Docker

```
docker run --name npgsql-duration -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_DB=db -e POSTGRES_USER=dbuser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbpassword -d postgres
```

Comment: In general, it's never reliable to just do a single sample when benchmarking - it's possible that various startup times (e.g. JITting) just cause random delays. I recommend doing a proper benchmark (possibly with BenchmarkDotNet) to get reliable results.

Comment: Indeed I tested the same scenario in AWS using EC2 and RDS and the times are definitely much closer to each other.
Thanks anyway for the answer!